# Any way to reorder posts on Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

On Google Plus pages, my posts are always listed in time order.
When a new visitor hits my Google page, I would prefer to show them posts at the top of the page, that are most likely going to get engagement and clicks to content links on my website. Otherwise my best posts could be far down the page which they would be less likely to see or scroll down to. Is there any way I can manually reorder posts on my Google Plus page?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Plus was retired long ago.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to either manually re-order the posts or to create sticky posts (posts that always sit at top).

You can at least edit the About of the Page and add links to the more important or introductory posts in either the Story or Links section. This will in some way provide a similar function for custom ordered or sticky posts.